# CSS Progress Bar

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I am trying to hide a progress bar after a certain amount of seconds and show a div.
I have coded this jsFiddle but does not seem to be working.

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/CnkDe)

Comment: what are you searching for exactly? What script do you have so far?

Comment: @Theolodis , The jsFiddle is what I have so far. I am having problems trying to hide the progress circle after a certain amount of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

**you can do this easly in css**

```css
.blue{
 width: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
 height:30px;
 left:40px;
 top:30px;
 padding:5px;
 }
 .blue>div{
 background-color:red;
 height:25px;
 width:50px;
 top:10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="blue" ><div>20%</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need browser prefixes:

```
@keyframes bubbly
{...}

@-moz-keyframes bubbly /* Firefox */
{...}

@-webkit-keyframes bubbly /* Safari and Chrome */
{...}mymove

@-o-keyframes bubbly /* Opera */
{...}
```

So it works in almost all browsers.